# Protocol for when Questioner accepts then un-accepts answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Hi - I just had a situation where I answered a question. The questioner accepted the answer. A few minutes later, after the questioner had checked out a link to an online article related to the question, the questioner then "unaccepted" my answer. The questioner added a comment that the code example in the article did not exactly match the scenario in their question. I am assuming that this is the reason the answer was unaccepted after initially being accepted.

Is it OK to ask the questioner to accept my answer again? I feel that the code example in the article was close enough to the scenario being described.

Comment: The buttons are too close together and my poor motor-control/carelessness cayse the wrong one to be clicked quite often. I'd guess others do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expand the answer to say how to bridge the gap between the scenario in the link and the situation the OP is facing. Presumably the article isn't quite enough to actually solve the OP's problem - and that should be the goal.

Comment: Great advice and in fact, I'd already tried to bridge that gap in a comment, but it didn't occur to me to edit the answer - thanks!